# Autohotkey get control from tooltip

Tags: controls, autohotkey, handle

I need to find the control's name to which its tooltip is linked.
I'm asking this because I need to control click within TeamCenter 10, but the control names keep changing just as you click on any of them. This makes it difficult to keep my code running smoothly when I need to repeat tasks.

If there is a better way of doing this (in Autohotkey), please let me know.

Comment: Can you give some examples of control names before and after clicking on them? The position of those controls could also be helpfull. Use the Window Spy utility to retrieve all this info.

Comment: Sure, using the aforementioned utility I clicked on a control that I'd like to use and it gave me: ClassNN: SWT_Window026

Comment: After clicking on another control and then on the original, it gave me the following (on Window Spy): ClassNN: SWT_Window027

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this (Replace `title of TeamCenter 10` with the exact title of the TeamCenter window as shown in Window Spy):

```
F1::
; Retrieve the control name for each control in a window:
WinGet, List, ControlList, title of TeamCenter 10
; Examine the individual control names one by one, using a parsing loop:
Loop, Parse, List, `n
{
    If InStr(A_LoopField, "SWT_Window02") ; use only the part of the control name that is always shown in Window Spy
         ControlClick, %A_LoopField%, title of TeamCenter 10
            break
}
return
```

https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/WinGet.htm#ControlList